# Correct datatype for a variable

Tags: c

I have a question like this: 
Which of the following is the correct datatype for the variable like this:

```
a = 23.5

a) float
b) double
c) long double
d) None
```

According to me, it should be double. Because, if we

```
 float a = 23.5
```

Then, actually, we are initializing a float variable by a double constant. Am I right  saying that it is option b?

Comment: The conversion would be resolved at compile time.  Any of options (a), (b) or (c) could be used.  Using option (b) is a reasonable choice with the minimal information given.

Comment: Exactly. I went with option (b) as well. However, the answer was option (a), I guess the answer might be incorrect.

Comment: The "correct" answer was (a) ? Now that's plain stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what type you need for `a` to be in your program logic, not what type of value it's initialized.

Yes, `float a = 23.5;`, there is a conversion from the `double` literal `23.5` to the `float` variable `a`, but it's fine. For instance, to initialize a `double` variable to `42.0`, people usually use

```
double a = 42;
```

in which `42` is of type `int`, instead of the longer

```
double a = 42.0;
```

So in my opinion, `float`, `double`, or `long double` can all be considered correct here.

Comment: Also, I have a doubt. If I declare a variable as, `float a = 2.2`. Then basically, I am initialising a float variable by a double. Now, if I print using `printf("%f",a)`, then before printing the float is upgraded to a double right? So, basically conversion takes place at two steps. While declaration, a double is converted to a float and then before printing, it is again upgraded to a double?

Comment: *Yes*. The second step is done only if you printf (or similar variadic funcions).

Comment: Alright. Got it. I really appreciate all of you helping me. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare this variable as double, float, or long double.

The difference is in the range of the type.

For example (one possible way):

```
float- 4 bytes
double - 8 bytes
long double - 12 bytes
```

You can see more details here: http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html

Comment: Note that there are platforms where `sizeof(double) == sizeof(long double)` and others where `sizeof(long double) == 16`.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it was an example of possible values of this types.
I've edited the answer to clarify this fact.

Comment: But I guess the answer might be float because, considering the number that they have given, that is, 23.5, it should be stored in a variable occupying minimum space.

Comment: If you want to store this variable in minimum amount of space, so float should be the answer. Notice that you can declare this var also in the other types and it will just take (a little) more memory.

Answer (score 0):

"It depends on" is the right answer.

There are more options then the three you mention.

- If yo can safely assume that your numbers are either an integer, or
  an integer +1/2 then storing 2 * i in an integral type may be the
  right choice.
- Another option is a rational number. There are
  libraries out there for this.